# How to refresh or redirect users after they allowed to get chrome browser notifications?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification

Is it possible in Chrome using JavaScript or PHP to refresh page or redirect users to a specific page, after user pushed [Allow] button in notification pop-up (example of notification request popup: http://prntscr.com/7ataxu)?

Comment: `window.location.assign` JavaScript API. And all other `window.location` methods can be helpful - MDN Docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification

```
 Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
      // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
      if (permission === "granted") {
        //redirect using javascript here window.location
      }
    });
```